# Receive adal-angular4/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3 error when using adal-angular4 v 4.0.12 and angular v 4.0.1

Tags: angular, typescript, adal, adal-angular4

If I am missing any pertinent information, please let me know.

I am trying to build out a web application that uses adal-angular4 for authentication with Azure AD.  I am running into the below compilation error:

> ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module C:/Users/elmerm/source/repos/TxDOT POC Base/node_modules/adal-angular4/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/elmerm/source/repos/TxDOT POC Base/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/elmerm/source/repos/TxDOT POC Base/src/app/app.module.ts
>       at syntaxError (C:\Users\elmerm\source\repos\TxDOT POC Base\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
>       at simplifyInContext (C:\Users\elmerm\source\repos\TxDOT POC Base\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
>       at StaticReflector.simplify (C:\Users\elmerm\source\repos\TxDOT POC Base\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
>       at StaticReflector.annotations (C:\Users\elmerm\source\repos\TxDOT POC Base\node_modules@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
>       at _getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Users\elmerm\source\repos\TxDOT POC Base\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
>       at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\Users\elmerm\source\repos\TxDOT POC Base\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
>       at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (C:\Users\elmerm\source\repos\TxDOT POC Base\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
>       at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\Users\elmerm\source\repos\TxDOT POC Base\node_modules@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
>       at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\Users\elmerm\source\repos\TxDOT POC Base\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:240:66)
>       at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (C:\Users\elmerm\source\repos\TxDOT POC Base\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:493:24)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

When reviewing the npm page for adal-angular4 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular4) it states it is compatible with Angular versions 4+.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding.  I've tried using an older version of adal-angular4 (v 3.0.6) but I receive the exact same error as above.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "inspinia",
  "version": "2.7.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.38.1",
    "adal-angular": "^1.0.17",
    "adal-angular4": "^4.0.12",
    "animate.css": "3.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
    "jvectormap": "1.2.2",
    "metismenu": "^2.5.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.6.6",
    "ngx-datetime-picker": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-select-dropdown": "^1.2.1",
    "peity": "^3.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "xml-js": "^1.6.11",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  }
}
```

Is this simply a compatibility issue and the current version of adal-angular4 is in fact not compatible with angular 4?  Or am I missing simple update?

Answer (score 0):

This was a version mismatch issue.  I upgraded the project to the most current version of Angular (8) and was able to proceed.